# Can't get NGINX to serve static files (js, css etc) from docker container service

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a container running, and the exposed port is 8080.

I'm using nginx to proxy pass to the docker container. However I can't get the js/css etc files to be served up. Below is some of the nginx config, and the request is coming in (according to the debug log on nginx) as `/auth/resources/7.0.0/admin/keycloak/js/authz/authz-services.js?`

They are coming up with a 404. The config is:

```
listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    location /keycloak/ {
            # proxy header
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host example.com/keycloak ;
            rewrite /keycloak/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
    location /auth/ {
            # proxy header
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            rewrite ^\/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
```

Comment: Well you should use your container name instead of 127.0.0.1 in your NGINX configuration

Comment: Possibly. However I do hit the container with this config, just not for the js and css.